# Syntax error on putting value on external server

Tags: php, html

Why it says syntax error and could not feel the form with this no. Hey guys today I am trying to put my number on external site and login without opening it but it couldn't work what is the problem I don't know. Any type of help is greatly appreciated

```
 <?php
    $phone=$_REQUEST['9155499248'];
        function send_sms($phone) {
            if (!function_exists('curl_init')) {
                echo "Error : Curl library not installed";
                return FALSE;
            }
    $user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36";

            // LOGIN TO TOPPER

            $url =  "https://www.toppr.com/signup/";
            $parameters = array("email"=>"$phone","button"=>"Signup");

            $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($parameters));
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parameters);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, FALSE);
                $result = curl_exec ($ch);
            curl_close ($ch);

            // SEND OTP AGAIN AND AGAIN

    ?>
```

And now this is the source code of site on which I am trying to put My no. And login automatically.**this is not my code**

```
<form action="/signup/" method="post" class="mdAuth_form">
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="">
    <div class="mdAuth_inputGroup js-input-group">
        <label class="mdAuth_inputGroup_label">Enter your phone number</label>
        <input type="text" name="email" class="inputText mdAuth_inputGroup_input">
        <label class="mdAuth_inputGroup_error js-error"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="ac mt-20 mb-25">
        <button class="button button-big button-arrowed button-green mdAuth_centerBtn -strk" data-strk='{ "e": "ui.tapped", "ui_element_name": "submit_email"}'>
            Signup <span class="arrowRight white inline-block ml-20"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Anyone reply instead of downvoting.......plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code is working,
only my modification: 
from:

```
<form action="/signup/" method="post" class="mdAuth_form">
```

to

```
<form action="https://www.toppr.com/signup/" method="post" class="mdAuth_form">
```

and from:

```
$user_agent = "Mozilla/5...."
```

to:

```
$user_agent = $_SERVER ['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
```

screenshot result:
https://s31.postimg.org/joj27wpp7/screenshot_2016_07_30_12_39_41.png

Comment: Thanks a lot @Adam p.

Comment: But why you modify the form action code this is not my code this is the source code of that site on which i am trying to automaticaly fiil form with php.......which i posted above

Comment: Precisely because I obviously do not know the test your server, so we had to add the full path. The **/signup/** path only operate on your server.

Comment: Thanks one again @Adam p. But can you say me the syntax error that I face in my php